# Object Oriented AS 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm new to OOP AS 3.0, so.. I have a question.

I have two files `Main.as` and `LoadTheXML.as`

in the `LoadTheXML` class I have `loadTheXML` function, in there `sortXML` function and in there an array `picturePathList` that I want to use in `Main.as`

in `Main.as` I have a code that launches the loadTheXML function:

```
var loadedXML:LoadTheXML = new LoadTheXML(urlVar);
```

so...  In Main.as I'd like to write:

```
            var rand:Number = Math.round(Math.random() * (a - 1));
            var mainLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            var mainRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(picturePathList[rand]);
            mainLoader.load(mainRequest);
            mainLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, mainLoaded);

            function mainLoaded(e:Event):void {
                mainPicPlacementX = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (mainLoader.width / 2);

            so on and so on.... 
            }
```

How should I call the picturePathList array from LoadTheXML class.

Thanks!!!

HERE I'll put the files - please see, because I didn't get what to do and how... [The Files](http://www.filesonic.com/file/1926116314/Flash_Gallery.rar)

I want the above mentioned code to be moved to Mainc.as I guess this will have more logic, and anyway I'd like to see how it's done.. If you find some tutorial I'd like to see that too.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general AS3 is asynchronous; it means, it should not wait for to complete the first statement before it go to the 2nd statement.

So u should listen an event object to check whether the task has been completed or not. You can attain this EventDispatcher object.

So u should dispatch an event object in `sortXML` function.

```
dispatchEvent ( new Event ( Event.COMPLETE ) );
```

and in the `Main.as`.

```
private function init():void
{
    loadedXML = new LoadTheXML(urlVar);
    loadedXML.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE, handleXMLLoaded );
}

private function handleXMLLoaded (e:Event):void
{
   var rand:Number = Math.round(Math.random() * (a - 1));
   var mainLoader:Loader = new Loader();
   var mainRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(loadedXML.picturePathList[rand]);
   mainLoader.load(mainRequest); 
   .....
   .....   
}
```

Comment: could you take a look at the files... Thanks!

Comment: Simple.  1. load the `xml` file in the `loadTheXML` class, and within `COMPLETE` handler store the values in the array and dispatch it.
   2.In `Main` class `loadedXML.picturePathList[rand]`. thats all. Array should be the public variable.

Comment: Benny Geo, could you please do the changes? because I'm somewhere wrong, and can't figure out where... If you just do the changes and upload the files.. will be greatly appreciated. Thanks anyway for your support!

Comment: Benny Geo, well I made the changes, but have a problem, in the LoadTheXML class I have declared public var picturePathList and there's a function LoadTheXML.

In Main.as I'm trying to call it but it says it's undefined property... why? How should I make that array be avaliable in Main.as?

Answer (score 2):

Make your `LoadToXML` object's `picturePathList` property publicly accesible via a getter method:

```
public class LoadTheXML
{
    private var _picturePathList:Array;

    public function get picturePathList():Array
    {
        return _picturePathList;

    }// end function

    // ...

}// end class
```